# MEAN stack delete request has 404 not found error

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, express

My post request and list all request are working fine, but I have problem getting my delete request to work. I have tested in Postman, but still have error. I think my delete url is fine, I can console log and see the item id been selected and show at the end of the url when making the request, I don't know what 's wrong.

delete.component.ts

```
deleteItem(): void {
    console.log(this.currentItem._id);
    alert("You had redeemed free food "+this.currentItem.itemToDonate);
    this.charityService.deleteItem(this.currentItem._id).subscribe(
      () => console.log("All of this food item has been redeemed"),
      (err) => console.log(err)
    )
  }
```

charity.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { identifierModuleUrl } from '@angular/compiler';
//import { DonateComponent } from '../donate/donate.component';

const AUTH_API = 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/donate';

const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
  };

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})


//post new donates to the database, list all items on the beneficiary page
//update quantity after redeem, delete item if the quantity is 0
export class CharityService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  
    donate(itemToDonate: string, quantity: number): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post(AUTH_API, {
            itemToDonate, quantity
          }, httpOptions);
    }

    listItem(): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.get(AUTH_API, {});
    }

    receive(id: string): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.put(`${AUTH_API}/update/${id}`,  httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        catchError((err, caught) => {
          console.error(err);
          throw err;
        })
      );
    }

    getItem(id: string): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.get(`${AUTH_API}/${id}`);
    }

    deleteItem(id: string): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.delete(`${AUTH_API}/${id}`)
      
    }
}
```

route.js

```
const controller_donate = require("../controllers/donate.controller");
const controller_receive = require("../controllers/receive.controller");
const controller_list = require("../controllers/list.controller");
const controller_delete = require("../controllers/delete.controller");

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.header(
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            "x-access-token, Origin, Content-Type, Accept"

        );
       
        next();
    });

    app.post("/api/auth/donate", controller_donate.donate);
    app.get("/api/auth/donate", controller_list.donations);

    app.put("/api/auth/donate/update/:id", controller_receive.receive);
    app.delete("/api/auth/donate/:id", controller_delete.delete);
};
```

delete.controller.js

```
const db = require("../models");
const Donate = db.donate;
const { donate } = require("../models");

exports.delete = (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    donate.findByIdAndRemove(id)
    .then(data => {
        if (!data) {
            res.status(404).send({ message: "Cannot delete item" });
        } else {
            res.status(200).send("This item is been redeemed");
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: In case you are not using mongoose the "id" param is read from URL as string and if your "id" field in DB is of integer type it might not work and the data wont be found. Can you cross check that.

Comment: @MohammadAslam I am using Mongoose, the id is a string generated by the database, I had console log the id, and it does get the id correctly, I don't know why it is not working in the url.